# Can't run a guest OS using QEMU in host Ubuntu

Tags: arm, emulation, qemu

I'd like to run a Debian OS .iso image for ARM processors using QEMU in a host running Ubuntu (over an x86 architecture).

I executed the following line in a terminal:

`aaron@aaron-HP-ZBook-14:~/Descargas$ qemu-system-arm -machine sabrelite -cdrom debian-10.7.0-arm64-netinst.iso -m 1024`

But then, the following window appears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB2PZ.png

I don't know why Debian OS is not initiating after executing the previous line. Instead, a QEMU command line interface appears waiting for the user to enter some commands.

Thanks in advance!

Aarón.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you try to run qemu and only see the monitor there is likely something wrong with your image.

In this case you are attempting to boot "debian-netinst" which is the debian network-install image. If you want to emulate a debian-arm image I would recommend following [this tutorial](https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2016/11/03/installing-debian-on-qemus-32-bit-arm-virt-board/) to get debian-arm up and running.

[Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ErezBinyamin/Scripts/master/misc/setup_qemu_arm_debian.sh) is a script that will automate the process in that tutorial

The script runs *two* QEMU commands. The first is a lengthy install process that should extract a debian initrd/kernel. The second QEMU command will boot the actual image. After the second command runs you should see the QEMU monitor open in a window. Use  `ctrl+alt+(1 or 2)` to switch to the terminal/gui display

Comment: Hi Lenna, thanks for the answer. I tried to execute the script but no success :(.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Hi Lenna, thanks for the answer. I tried to execute the script but no success :(. It downloads the vmlinuz kernel and initrd filesystem and it seems to install the debian-arm into the 5G disk. But finally, when running the installed system, it throws again the QEMU monitor instead of a windows showing the Debian OS running.

Comment: sorry, I was editting my comment above while you answered me xD

Comment: Try `ctrl+alt+(1 or 2)`

Comment: Perfect! It finally worked. Thanks @Lenna !

Comment: Happy to help :) Feel free to follow up with any other questions you have and I’ll try to expand/elaborate my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to boot a 64-bit Arm CDROM image on a board which is 32-bit only, so this is never going to work.

More generally, most Arm boards will not simply boot from a CDROM image passed via the -cdrom option, because they don't have firmware/BIOS images which will run on QEMU and do the handling of booting from CD. Many boards don't even have an IDE or SCSI interface that a CDROM drive could be plugged into!

You should decide whether you want (a) to boot an image on the sabrelite board, (b) to boot a 32-bit arm image, but you don't care which board (c) to boot an arm64 kernel, and find a suitable tutorial or set of instructions accordingly. Lenna's link is good for option (b); there's a similar tutorial also for option (c). I don't know of any sabrelite specific instructions.

It's worth reading the [QEMU documentation section on choosing an Arm board model](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/target-arm.html#choosing-a-board-model) -- unless you have a strong reason why you want to use a particular board model and a kernel that you know works on that board model, then 'virt' is usually a better choice. Even 'virt' won't boot directly off a cdrom, though, unless you also pass it a suitable UEFI bios image.